# CollapseAll items of a treeview within Wpf application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, treeview

I have a WPF application , in which i have a treeview control .

I'd like to collapse all the items by clicking into a button. I tried this:

```
 private void buttonParam_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
//handling
    this.arborescence.IsExpanded = false;
        }
```

but it didn't worked. What are the reasons of this error? How can i change my snippet to do this task?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is by looping through all nodes and collapse them 1 by 1.

```
private void cmdCollapse_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (TreeViewItem item in treeview.Items)
        CollpaseTreeviewItems(item);
}

void CollapseTreeviewItems(TreeViewItem Item)
{
    Item.IsExpanded = false;

    foreach (TreeViewItem item in Item.Items)
    {
        item.IsExpanded = false;

        if (item.HasItems)
            CollapseTreeviewItems(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

@JROs [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20494843/75500) will not work when data-binding to items, it will only when directly adding `TreeViewItem`s into the `TreeView`.

I made this extension method that will retrieve the matching `TreeViewItem` for the current object in the iteration:

```
namespace System.Windows.Controls
{
  using System.Linq;
  public static class TreeViewExtensions
  {
    public static void SetExpansion(this TreeView treeView, bool isExpanded) =>
      SetExpansion((ItemsControl)treeView, isExpanded);

    static void SetExpansion(ItemsControl parent, bool isExpanded)
    {
      if (parent is TreeViewItem tvi)
        tvi.IsExpanded = isExpanded;

      if (parent.HasItems)
        foreach (var item in parent
            .Items
            .Cast<object>()
            .Where(it => it != null)
            .Select(it => GetTreeViewItem(parent, it, isExpanded)))
          SetExpansion(item, isExpanded);
    }

    static TreeViewItem GetTreeViewItem(
      ItemsControl parent, object item, bool isExpanded)
    {
      if (item is TreeViewItem tvi)
        return tvi;

      var result = ContainerFromItem(parent, item);
      if (result == null && isExpanded)
      {
        parent.UpdateLayout();
        result = ContainerFromItem(parent, item);
      }
      return result;
    }

    static TreeViewItem ContainerFromItem(ItemsControl parent, object item) =>
      (TreeViewItem)parent.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
treeView.SetExpansion(isExpanded: true / false);
```

Comment: Shimmy is absolutely right here - if the tree is databound, the items aren't instances of TreeViewItem, they're instances of whatever object you're bound to, so there are some hoops to jump through to get to the visual TreeViewItem.

Comment: add a null check for the item in the SetExpansion method, works perfectly :)

Comment: @Harxish I don't have the code handy now but I've updated the code to reflect your request.